# How to display floating-point rounded to .001 with Irvine32 WriteFloat, not printf

Tags: assembly, masm, irvine32

I am very new to assembly language so bear with me...

I have a floating-point that I have rounded to the nearest .001, but still displays as something like +1.6670000E+000. I would like it to display simply as 1.667.

Here is my code for dividing and rounding the numbers:

```
fild    num_a
fidiv   num_b
fimul   thousand
frndint
fidiv   thousand
fst     a_div_b
```

And here is my code for displaying the float:

```
mov     eax, num_a
call    WriteDec
mov     edx, OFFSET divide
call    WriteString
mov     eax, num_b
call    WriteDec
mov     edx, OFFSET equals
call    WriteString
fld     a_div_b
call    WriteFloat
call    CrLf
```

I looked a lot online and there were many answers on how to round numbers, but they still all displayed in the extended format. I am using the irvine32 library.

Comment: If you don't have access to a function that allows specifying the format (e.g. `printf`) then separate the integer and the fractional part yourself and print those with a dot between them according to however many digits you want.

Comment: That makes sense, thank you! I understand how to get the integer part, but I don't know how I would get the fractional part, let alone only printing 3 digits of it.

Comment: Once you got the integer part, subtract from the original number, then multiply by 1000 to get 3 digits.

Comment: You can isolate the fractional part with `x - (int)x` (using truncation towards 0, not the default round to nearest, e.g. with SSE3 `fisttp`.  Otherwise you could get a negative fractional part, and an integer part that's 1 too high.  Of course this is much easier with SSE2 where you can use `cvttsd2si` instead of using legacy x87 at all).  To get the leading 3 digits of that, you're already using hacks like multiplying by 1000 to make some of the fractional part integer.

Comment: Oh man, it's so obvious once it's explained to me. Last question, how would I deal with with a leading zero? If I'm understanding correctly, 1.062 would be converted to .062 * 1000 = 62. Then concatenating the numbers would become 1.62. I could maybe use if statements to check how many digits are in the decimal number, but is there a simpler way than that?

Comment: You might as well do the number to string conversion yourself, just divide by 10 in a loop and take the remainder each time. That's the easiest for the leading zeroes.

Answer (score 2):

An even a simpler modification to the approach discussed in comments:

Multiply by 1000 and *convert* that to integer with `fistp` (with the default rounding to nearest), instead of just rounding to an integer-valued `long double` using `frndint`.

**The low 3 decimal digits of that integer are the fractional part of your number.**  i.e. you now have decimal fixed-point.  `div` by 1000 gives you quotient (integer part) and remainder (fractional part).  **Print both parts with a `.` between them.**

You'll want to do manual int->string conversion ([How do I print an integer in Assembly Level Programming without printf from the c library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13166064/how-do-i-print-an-integer-in-assembly-level-programming-without-printf-from-the/46301894#46301894)) or otherwise print leading zeros in the fractional part.  (So `2.062` doesn't turn into `2.62`)

---

This is easier than separating into integer and fractional parts in FP, which would require rounding with truncation toward zero to make sure you got a non-negative fractional part.  Integer division naturally truncates towards zero, but legacy x87 FP->int conversion can only use the default rounding mode.  (Except with SSE3 `fisttp`.)  SSE1/2 had XMM FP->int conversions with truncation or current rounding mode since they were introduced, like `cvttsd2si` vs. `cvtsd2si`

**Downside: overflows a 32-bit integer for smaller float inputs**, because a single 32-bit integer has to hold `x * 1000`.

The other way is to use `x - (int)x` to get the fractional part and only multiplying *that* fractional part by `1000.0`.  That leads to `(int)x` in a separate integer from the the fractional part, with `x*1000` only existing as floating point, not `int32_t`.

---

Fun fact:

AVX512DQ has an instruction for getting the fractional part directly: [VREDUCESD xmm1, xmm2, xmm3/m64, imm8](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/vreducesd) (and ss/ps/pd versions). It's the part that [SSE4 roundsd](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/roundsd) / vrndscalesd would discard when keeping the integer part.  Even more fun: can keep a specified number of fraction bits. But of course those are binary fraction bits, not decimal places.

Most x86 CPUs have SSE4.1 these days, but only Skylake-X high-end desktops and modern Xeons have AVX512DQ. :/  And Ice Lake laptops.